# How to do a partial update methods for row

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm trying to write a generic function to do a partial update for row, Here is what I got so far.

```
func GetSetByUpdateOptions(x interface{}) (string, error) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(x)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return "", errors.New("invalid_options_tag")
    }
    res := "SET "
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        setTemplate := "%s=%v, "
        field := t.Field(i).Tag.Get("sql_set")
        value := v.Field(i).Interface()
        // NEED TO CHECK VALUE HERE
        if field == "" {
            return "", errors.New("invalid_options_tag")
        }
        res += fmt.Sprintf(setTemplate, field, value)
    }
    return res, nil
}

type Optional struct {
    Field1 *int `set:"field1"` // might be nil if not set
    Field2 *int `set:"field2"` // might be nil if not set
}

func UpdateRow(o Optional) { // here because i want a partial update. field1 
    s, _ := GetSetByUpdateOptions(o)
    query := "UPDATE table SET status=" + s + " mtime=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) WHERE id = ?"
    // update
}
```

Just wondering how to define an input type since using an interface as input for GetSetByUpdateOptions seems not a good idea and How to filter some part of options because I want a partial update?

Comment: If your function is supposed to accept any struct type then using `interface{}` as the input type is the only good idea. The second part of your question is not entirely clear to me. Maybe show example input and output, or try to be more specific.

Comment: This is susceptible to SQL injections. Make GetSetByUpdateOptions return a string with placeholders, a slice of interface{} containing the values, and an error.

Comment: @mkopriva, for example, I want only update field1 then field2 should be filtered.

Comment: @MaxHsu well you need some mechanism to indicate which fields to update and which to omit, how you do that is up to you. For example you could decide that `nil` fields should be omitted from the update, then the task is easy... however if you need to be able to also update columns to `NULL` then the above approach becomes less appropriate because a `nil` is the correct "value" to be used for that purpose.